# Play/Akka - What happens if my scheduled task is in progress on shutdown?

Tags: multithreading, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I'm scheduling a long running task with Akka using the Runnable interface like this:

```
val myTask = system.scheduler.schedule(initialDelay, interval, new MyRunnable())
```

What exactly happens to the thread when Play is shutdown?  I can see that the code in my runnable stops executing, but it's unclear to me at what point the thread is interrupted and how to hook into this event within my runnable.  I have tried catching an InterruptedException (or any other) in my runnable but an exception is never thrown.  What would be the best way to gracefully cancel the thread?  I can call cancel on myTask but that just cancels the next scheduled execution.  I thought about passing the lifecycle object to MyRunnable so that it could create a stop hook but I'm not sure this is the best approach.

Comment: Just curious, but why are you explicitly scheduling tasks, instead of letting Akka take care of all of that for you?

Comment: I don't think this is possible.